# Stay on NewForm after submitting the form

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, redirect, newform, presaveaction

I have a requirement where Users need to stay on list's **NewForm.aspx** after submitting the item details.

They should be able to create as many items until they click on **Cancel** without redirecting to **AllItems.aspx**

I have tried below solutions but that did not entirely help.

1. Tried appending Source on **"New Item"** button but that allows users to create an item only twice.
2. Redirecting to **NewForm** in **PreSaveAction** function before returning it to true but that will bypass column validations.

Is there anyone who has worked on a similar requirement? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If changing the `Source` query parameter works to redirect back to the New form, why not add a script *to the New form itself* that rewrites the `Source` query param every time the form loads?

That should make it endlessly redirect back to itself.

Or, if that affects the behavior of the Cancel button also, use the `PreSaveAction` to rewrite the `Source` param, so it only gets changed if the user hits the Save button.

---

To address your comment:

You can change the URL by setting `window.location.href` directly.  So you could do something like

```
window.location.href = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + "?Source=" + window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
```

which would reset the URL to be the URL of the New form with a `Source` query param of the URL back to the New form.  However, setting `window.location.href` causes an immediate refresh to that new URL.  So you can't do that when the page first loads, or you'll end up in an endless loop of page refreshes.  You could *try* to do that in a `PreSaveAction` function, but that wouldn't really work either because the refresh to the new URL would happen before the form got submitted, so you would never be able to actually save any new items.

However, you can use `window.history.pushState()` to change the URL in the address bar *without* causing a page refresh.

So what you can do is set up a `PreSaveAction` function on the New form that looks something like this:

```
function PreSaveAction() {

    // build the new URL
    var newUrl = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + "?Source=" + window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;

    // push it to the history, effectively changing the current URL without causing a refresh
    window.history.pushState({ path: newUrl }, null, newUrl);

    // return true from the PreSaveAction to let the form submit
    return true;
}
```

Now when the form submits, the `Source` param will be the New form URL and the user will end up back on the New form.  The beauty of this is that the `PreSaveAction` function only gets called when the user clicks the Save button, so the `Source` redirect only gets added if the user is actually saving a new item, which means the Cancel button will still redirect back out to `AllItems.aspx`.

Now, you have tagged your question with [sharepoint-online](/questions/tagged/sharepoint-online).  I have not worked much with SharePoint Online, but through reading other people's questions, it's my understanding that adding Javascript to Modern pages in SharePoint Online isn't so straightforward, so I'm not sure what you would have to do to actually set up a `PreSaveAction` function on your New form page.  But that's what I would try to do to achieve the result you want.

Comment: How can I make changes to Source parameter without affecting the default Save and Cancel functionality ? I have seen lot of people saying the same and myself thought the same but could not find any solution for that so an example would be great.

Comment: @Ravi updated my answer with an example.

Comment: It works like charm. Will test more and let you know in case of any issues. Thank you so much @Dylan

Answer (score 0):

we can add the RedirectURL on existing SP button attribute:

```
<SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="savebutton2" RedirectUrl="https://..."
```